# Spontaneous symmetry breaking: proving the equivalence of two definitions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, symmetry-breaking

This question can be posed for both quantum and classical set-ups. For concreteness, let me consider a *local, classical Hamiltonian* $H$. The expectation values I consider are with respect to the usual classical partition function, i.e., $\langle \mathcal A \rangle = \frac{1}{Z} \int \mathcal A e^{-\beta H}$ (suppressing the integration variable).

Let $\mathcal O(\boldsymbol r)$ be a *local, physical observable* which would be zero if the system obeys a particular symmetry. There are two common ways of characterizing the spontaneous breaking of this symmetry:

1. **Long-range order:** $$\boxed{\lim_{|\boldsymbol{r-r'}| \to \infty} \langle \mathcal O(\boldsymbol r) \mathcal O(\boldsymbol{r'}) \rangle \neq 0}. $$
2. **The double limit:** $$\boxed{\lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{V \to \infty} \langle \mathcal O (\boldsymbol r) \rangle_h \neq 0},$$ where the average is with respect to the perturbed Hamiltonian $H_h = H + h \int \mathcal O(\boldsymbol r) \mathrm d^D \boldsymbol r$ and $V$ denotes the system size (i.e., the first limit is the thermodynamic limit).

Can one show that these conditions are equivalent? Clearly the locality of the Hamiltonian is essential (but the partition function is not a local object, so one cannot simply factorize, e.g., the two-point function in the first definition!)

Alternatively, is there a counter-example to the claim that these two definitions are equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this can be proved.

Let me first discuss this in the classical case, and then give you pointers to where you can learn more about the quantum case.

You first have to be careful, when writing down your expectations, to specify the state with respect to which you are actually computing the expectation. In this respect, the physicists' habit of denoting expectation simply by generic brackets $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is *very bad*. There is no problem for your "double limit" expectation (provided you let $h\to 0$ using positive values only), but the expectation in your "long-range order" case is ambiguous and results actually depend on what it is supposed to mean.

Indeed, when a first-order phase transition occurs (which is precisely what you are interested in), there are infinitely-many different Gibbs measures describing your system in the thermodynamic limit. The set of all such measures is always a simplex, that is, a convex set such that each element can be written in a unique way as a convex combination of *extremal elements*, the latter being those that cannot be decomposed in a non-trivial way. In the Ising model, for instance, the (translation invariant) extremal measures are those corresponding to the usual $+$ and $-$ phases. In a sense, the only physically relevant measures are the extremal ones, the other describing statistical mixtures and thus not containing any additional interesting physics.

The first statement is then that a measure is extremal if and only if it is mixing. The latter means precisely that the expectation of the product of any pair of local observables $\langle \mathcal{O}(r) \mathcal{O}(r')\rangle$ converges, as $|r'-r|\to\infty$ to the product of the expectations $\langle \mathcal{O}(r) \rangle \langle \mathcal{O}(r')\rangle$. Note that this is an "if and only if" statement, so the claim fails if the state you are considering is not extremal (for example, it fails for the Ising model if you consider the state obtained using free or periodic boundary conditions and zero magnetic field).

As for the second part (with the "double limit"), the point is that by taking this limit (with $h\downarrow 0$, that is, $h\to 0$ using positive values only) you are reaching (in the limit) precisely the extremal state under which the observable has largest expected value. For example, if you take the limit $h\downarrow 0$ in the Ising model, you will get the expected value of the observable under the $+$ state.

The equivalence you want thus immediately follows if the state you use for the "long-range order" is the state you get by letting $h\downarrow 0$ in the "double limit".

The above statements are standard and can be found in several places, among which [our book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html), [Georgii's book](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/128575) or [Simon's book](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/5262.html).

Similar claims also hold in the quantum case. Precise statements and proofs can be found, for instance, in Chapter IV of [Simon's book](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/5262.html).

Comment: Great answer, this is what makes stackexchange awesome! Found the claimed statement on pages 83, 84 of Simon's book.

Comment: @RyanThorngren : Thanks! And thanks also for providing the precise pages, as I don't have his book with me at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer  and  the  free pdf book.                           
 ( Recently I bought one, since I became  a frequent user of this book---)

Comment: @dengaku Thanks a lot for your appreciation!

Comment: @dengaku No, if you have more than one, you automatically have infinitely many, since any convex combination of two Gibbs states is still a Gibbs state (e.g., all measures of the form $\alpha\mu^+ + (1-\alpha)\mu^-$ with $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$ in the Ising model). On the other hand, you can have finitely many **extremal** Gibbs states (this is the case for the 2d Ising model, in which $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are the only extremal ones; but this is not the case in higher dimensions, where you have infinitely many extremal Gibbs states).

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your answer. I would like to know  which implication is  
  model independent,  and which part requires  information  of the model. 
(I recall  Prop. 6.91 of Yvan's book  which follows from   the DLR condition only, 
since  choosing a boundary condition (6.9.1) and choosing a special double limit 
 seem to me similar recipes to make an  extremal thermal state.) 
Under the assumption of the sharpness of phase transitionm   in the Abdelmalek's answer,  can one prove    1) implies 2)   as a general statement without referring to a model? 
What about 2) to 1)?

Comment: @dengaku : as I say in my answer, proving 2) $\Leftrightarrow$ 1) is "immediate" if the state used in 1) is the state you obtain by taking the $h\downarrow 0$ limit in 2). Indeed the latter state is always extremal. This means that $\lim_{r\to\infty}\langle \mathcal{O}(0)\mathcal{O}(r) \rangle = \langle \mathcal{O}(0) \rangle^2$. Obviously the right-hand side is nonzero iff the left-hand side is nonzero, and $\langle \mathcal{O}(0) \rangle = \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \langle \mathcal{O}(0) \rangle_h$.

Comment: Many thanks. This is a  perfect  answer. However,  the  posed  question  addresses ``spontaneous'' symmetry breakdown, whereas  this   equivalence   holds for any cluster  state,  not necessarily  extremal Gibbs  states.  I   want to  know  the relationship between our familiar  definition of SSB using  the double limit (in any  text book)  and the  sophisticated  def  based on  DLR  measures  (Def 6.47 in Frieli-Velenik book).   Let  G be some inner  group (such as global rotation). If G is spontaneously  broken, can  we  construct  extremal Gibbs states  by the double limit procedure ?

Comment: @dengaku  The answer to your question is yes. If the Hamiltonian (or rather, the potential) is $G$-invariant, then necessarily the set of all Gibbs states is also $G$-invariant (Theorem 6.45 in the book). The corresponding extremal Gibbs states can then be obtained by using a suitable double-limit procedure. An example of this is given in Section 6.11 of the book (in the case of translation-invariant states for simplicity). The measure $\mu$ in Proposition 6.91 can be, for instance, the measure obtained with periodic boundary condition.

Answer (score 2):

Yvan covered the simplest situation where the state used in 1) about the long-range order is an extremal say $+$ state. However for a ferromagnetic scalar valued model like Ising or lattice $\phi^4$ the equivalence of 1) and 2) still holds but is much more difficult to prove. Here the state I am talking about in 1) is precisely the one Yvan said one should avoid, namely, zero magnetic field and free boundary conditions so there is nothing to break the symmetry between $+$ and $-$ spins. If one can prove that there are only two extremal states $\langle\cdot\rangle_{+}$ and $\langle\cdot\rangle_{-}$ then showing 1) implies 2) is not hard. But if one does not know how to rule out the possibility of more extremal states, then showing 1) implies 2) is more challenging.

You can find a proof in the case of a ferromagnetic (unbounded spin) $\phi^4$ model due to Chandra, Guadagni and myself in section 4.7 of Chandra's thesis:
[Construction and Analysis of a Hierarchical Massless Quantum Field Theory](https://libraetd.lib.virginia.edu/public_view/2r36tx772).

and for $\{-1,1\}$-valued Ising spins in this article by Aizenman, Duminil-Copin and Sidoravicius:
[Random Currents and Continuity of Ising Model’s Spontaneous Magnetization](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00220-014-2093-y).

Note this question is about a general circle of ideas called "sharpness of phase transitions". Namely one may have several competing definitions of the critical inverse temperature $\beta_c$. For example one could take $\beta_{c,\chi}$ as the infimum of $\beta$'s where the susceptibility diverges. One can define $\beta_{c,SM}$ as the infimum of $\beta$'s where the spontaneous magnetization is nonzero (i.e., item 2) in the question above). One can also define $\beta_{c,LRO}$ as the infimum of $\beta$'s where one has long-range order, i.e., item 1) above for the symmetric $h=0$ state. In general one has
$$
\beta_{c,\chi}\le \beta_{c,SM}\le \beta_{c,LRO}
$$
but one can sometimes show equality as in the literature on sharpness of phase transitions.

Comment: Yes, this is true +1 . Note, however, that my caution (to avoid non-extremal states) was really addressing the "so one cannot simply factorize, e.g., the two-point function in the first definition" part of the OP question, that is, whether clustering occurs. This *requires* extremality (of course you know that, this comments is for potential readers who may get confused).

Comment: @YvanVelenik I'm somewhat confused. If I am given a Hamiltonian, is there a condition I can check in order to make sure that the two conditions above give the same point for the phase transition (assuming that all I know is that $\langle\cdot\rangle$ is the behavior in a generic (? - e.g. all but zero measure) Gibbs state/ground state)?

Comment: @YvanVelenik: +1 to you too. It is good to remind physicists that in the area of statistical mechanics one has available not only rigorous proofs of results but also precise definitions which can have subtle variants (e.g. which precise state or choice of thermodynamic limit prescription one is talking about) when the physics literature may give the impression there is only one definition.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: As Abdelmalek is saying, in Ising-type models, you are guaranteed that this is the case. In general, you are guaranteed that this is the case if your state is extremal. However, the latter cannot be read from the Hamiltonian: it depends on the state. One way to check that your state is extremal is to check that clustering occurs.

Comment: What's an example of a phase transition which is not sharp?

Comment: @RyanThorngren : For example, in the 2d clock model with a large enough number of states, the 2-point function (i) does not decay to $0$ at low enough temperatures, (ii) decays as a power law at intermediate temperatures, (iii) decays exponentially fast at high enough temperatures. This was proved by Fröhlich and Spencer in the 1980s.

Comment: The paper I mentioned is [this one](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01208273). The relevant claim is Theorem E.

Comment: The free version of the article on the KT transition mentioned by Yvan is here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103920388 Also, the earliest rigorous result about sharpness of phase transitions that I know is Aizenman's 1985 PRL article "Absence of an intermediate phase for a general class of one-component ferromagnetic models": https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.54.839

Comment: > In general $\beta_{c,\chi} \le \beta_{c,SM}\le \beta_{c, LRO}$.
Is the implication  1. LRO $ \to$ 2. Non-zero double limit valid in general?
Does ``challenging"  mean some technical difficulty to prove 1 $\to$ 2, or  possible  violation   for some  models?  (I see the  third condition   is strictly weaker   due to  KT-phases.)  In  `Random currents'  1 $\to$ 2  is addressed  for  Ising. I  look for model-independent  relationship between 1 and 2  including  the  continuous  symmetry case.  What happens  when  2 holds  without 1 (continuous differentiability of the pressure)? Many thanks.

Comment: @dengaku  For a general equivalence result of this type, look at Theorem III.10.1 in [Simon's book](https://princetonup.degruyter.com/view/title/508021?tab_body=toc) (as well as the discussion following the proof).

Comment: Thanks for  useful information. However, Abdelmalek's 
 answer  seems  not harmonious with  JSP-paper https://archiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9708132 . At p230 of  Chandra's thesis,  $\beta_\chi:=\inf \{\beta| \chi<\infty \}$ , $\beta_{SM}:=\sup \{\beta| M^{+}>0\}$, $\beta=\frac{1}{T}$. I think  $\inf$ and $\sup$ seems   converse. Abdelmalek  said:  ``If one does  not  rule out the possibility of more extremal states, then showing 1 LRO) $\to$ 2 SMB) is more challenging." I consider  that  1 LRO) $\to$  2SMB   is surely valid      without knowing such possibility of more   extremal states.

Comment: At p234 of   Chandra it says   :In [68]  for generalized Ising models satisfying  GHS inequality,   LRO implies SMB,   $ \beta_{SM}\le \beta_{LRO}$.:
 Dose  this   really necessitate  GHS?   ``In general  one has $\beta_{SM}\le \beta_{LRO}$.''  Could you specify  the meaning of `in general'?
The  mentioned  papers show    $\beta_{SM}= \beta_{LRO}$ for some  Ising  type models.  Could you  suggest   a concrete model  for   $<$, i.e. Symmetry breakdown  without LRO and  the  reason for  this (peculiar) phenomena? Maybe,  Norbert was   asking a similar  thing--

Comment: @YvanVelenik: Many thanks. In  your  book of  Cambridge  BKT transition is discussed  in  9.6.1. It states 
``A sharp transition is expected between two exponential- algebraic decay.''
In my  stat mech books, however, it is  a priori assumed. What kind of (peculiar) things does one   need  to consider and exclude?
The mentioned 2D-clock model has three phases (i) (ii) (iii). Interesting.
Obviously  the transition between (i) and (iii) is  not sharp. Is transition between (i) and (ii) (which is related to the original question) and that between (ii) and (iii)  sharp?  Is it    proved ?

Comment: @dengaku Well, Fröhlich and Spencer proved that there is algebraic decay at low enough temperatures and it is easy to show that the decay is exponential at high enough temperatures. This implies the existence of (at least) one temperature at which the behavior changes. The problem is that there is no obvious monotonicity in this case that would guarantee that this transition temperature is well defined (and furthermore that there is no intermediate phase in which the behavior is still different). As far as I know, this is still open.

Comment: @dengaku For the clock model, all these transitions are expected to be sharp. I doubt that this has been proved. There has been substantial progress recently on proving sharpness, thanks to work by Duminil-Copin and collaborators, but this remains a difficult problem in general.