# Statistical physics of broken symmetry state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, many-body, ferromagnetism

If we are considering a system, like a paramagnet, above its critical temperature $T_c$ we can statistically describe it using a canonical ensemble:
$$
\langle A \rangle = Tr\left[ \rho A \right]; \quad \rho = \frac{e^{-\beta H}}{Tr\; e^{-\beta H}}.
$$
Let us further suppose that system obeys rotational $SO(3)$ symmetry. Now, the expectation value (and correlation functions in general) should also obey this symmetry. This can be easily seen if we denote arbitrary rotation operator by $U$:
$$
[\rho, U] = 0 \implies  \langle  U A U^{\dagger}\rangle = Tr\left[ \rho U A U^{\dagger} \right] = Tr\left[ U^{\dagger} \rho U A  \right] = Tr\left[ \rho A \right] = \langle A \rangle ,
$$
where we used the cyclic property of trace and the fact that density matrix commutes with rotation operator.

However, if we lower the temperature below the critical temperature $T_c$, the system transitions in the ferromagnetic phase, and the $SO(3)$ symmetry is broken. Even though the Hamiltonian still possesses the $SO(3)$ symmetry, the procedure we conducted above cannot be repeated, since we know that it is not true for magnetization (for example)
$$
 \langle  U M U^{\dagger}\rangle \neq  \langle  M\rangle.
$$
This means that the density matrix in the ferromagnetic (ordered) state is not determined by
$$
\rho = \frac{e^{-\beta H}}{Tr\; e^{-\beta H}}
$$
**How do we then do the statistical physics in the ordered (like ferromagnet) phase? What density matrix should we use? Does that mean that straightforward canonical ensemble does not apply?**

From this, we can conclude that ergodicity does not hold anymore.

Comment: The following link might help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480520/spontaneous-symmetry-breaking-proving-the-equivalence-of-two-definitions

Comment: Take a look at Exercise 2.1 of https://scipost.org/SciPostPhysLectNotes.11
If that doesn't answer your question, please edit to be more specific.